# Remove / Replace special characters, with exception

Tags: regex, postgresql, regexp-replace

I have a string, and I want to remove all special characters, including spaces.  Except, I want to leave the colon if it exists in the string.

I was using this, and it was sort of working, but appears to not replace parens, or back slash or dashes.......

```
TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(c.category_name,'[^:^0-9A-Za-z ]',''),' : ','|'), '\s+', '_', 'g'))
```

Please advise

Comment: What relevance is the outer `REGEXP_REPLACE` or `TRIM` to this question? Isn't this question just about `REGEXP_REPLACE(c.category_name,'[^:^0-9A-Za-z ]','')`?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the colon into the list of allowed characters

`[^0-9A-Za-z:]`: anything that is not a number, a letter or a colon.
`'g'`: apply the replacement as many time as needed (else it would stop at the 1st one)

```sql
select REGEXP_REPLACE('0.1[2]?ab cd:ef g&*(h)/ij;','[^0-9A-Za-z:]','','g');
 regexp_replace
----------------
 012abcd:efghij
```

Comment: Many thanks to all.  Multiple of these appear to be working!   Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `'g'` ("global") flag, so only the *first* unwanted character was being removed (replaced by blank).

Change:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(c.category_name, '[^:^0-9A-Za-z ]', '')
```

to:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(c.category_name, '[^:0-9A-Za-z ]', '', 'g')
```

Note: I removed the extra `^` from the regex, but leave it in if you want to keep `^` characters too.